# Can JavaScript call ActionScript code?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3

I'm new to Flash. I have created a flv player that can play videos dynamically based on a user selection in a list component. I would rather not develop the user interface in Flash. Meaning, I'd like to bag the list component. Mostly because I am not very savvy yet. Is it possible to have javascript call actionscript? I would like to invoke an actionscript function that would accept a url as a string. Is this even possible?

I am developing this using ActionScript 3 BTW.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Actionscript publishes available functions via the [`ExternalInterface`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/638/1/Basics-of-using-the-ExternalInterface/Page1.html), or any other discussing `ExternalInterface` usage.

Answer (score 5):

Look into ExternalInterface
http://www.adobe.ca/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Examples:
[Bi-Directional Actionscript/Javascript Communication in AS3](http://viget.com/inspire/bi-directional-actionscript-javascript-communication)

Good luck.